# Is this escaped shell command wrong

Tags: php, shell, exec, pngquant

Here is my escaped shell command which I run through exec command in PHP:

```
C:^\Program Files^\pngquant^\pngquant.EXE \"--force\" \"--ext=.png\" \"--\" \"F:\laragon\www\demo\images\uploads\43d67cba7a951378485882e5b515c825943f7d0a.png\"
```

I get return code 1 (i.e. error). On the other hand, if I run  `pngquant "--force" "--ext=.png" "--" "F:\laragon\www\demo\images\uploads\43d67cba7a951378485882e5b515c825943f7d0a.png"`directly in shell, it works fine.

Is there something wrong with the way I am escaping command and arguments.

**Edit 1:**
Here is my PHP exec command:

```
escapeshellcmd($this->cmd).' '.implode(' ', array_map('escapeshellarg', $args))
```

Where $this->cmd is  `C:\Program Files\pngquant\pngquant.EXE` and `print_r($args)` is

```
Array(    
    [0] => "--force",
    [1] => "--ext=.png",
    [2] => "--",
    [3] => "F:\laragon\www\demo\images\uploads\d3a2966596a94343b5a732368dcb79394a8d4d69.png"
)
```

Comment: You need to show us the actually command that you're executing like `shell_exec(...)` otherwise it's hard to see what's wrong.

Comment: escapeshellcmd($this->cmd).' '.implode(' ', array_map('escapeshellarg', $args))

Comment: ...now you need to show us the values of `$this->cmd` and `$arg`. Do you see where this is going? Please [edit] your question rather than using the comments.

Comment: You have not provided us with enough detail to reproduce your problem. Please take a look at [mcve] and then edit your question to help us diagnose your issue.

Comment: Hey @TomFenech, I just provided the values. Please help me with it.

Comment: You're either not showing us your actual code or your actual input. There's **no way** `escapeshellcmd` would produce an unquoted path with an unescaped space inside it. There's also no way `escapeshellarg` would quote all the arguments and then escape the quotes for some reason.

Comment: I actually did `print_r($this->cmd)` and `print_r($args)`. So it is the actual code, I believe. If you want the whole code, I can post that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `escapeshellarg($this->cmd).' '.implode(' ', array_map('escapeshellarg', $args))` cleared the error and image was also compressed. It's strange that `escapeshellcmd` puts control character(`^`) before `\`.